# List 2 packages from 1 DE Org to Appexchange

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review, unmanaged-package

I have a developer Org where we are creating an app for Appexchange. We created both Unmanaged and Managed forms of the same app in the Org. My question is whether its possible to get both these versions on the Appexchange from the same Org ?

[This very helpful Post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116209/how-to-host-an-unmanaged-package-on-salesforce-appexchange) answers half my question. I cannot put an unmanaged package for security review. My second question is whether I can at least have the Unmanaged package as a private listing with the Managed one as a public listing on appexchange ?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but why would you want to list a managed package if you are also listing the unmanaged package version? Isn't the whole point of a manager package to protect your ip?

Comment: Your first question - you mean that you have 2 packages in your org - one is managed and the other is unmanaged, and you want to list both of the in the appExchange?

Comment: Yes @ItaiShmida. Exactly.

Comment: @JannisBott- The managed package would be the full version of our product with apex code. The unmanaged would contain less code and more configuration like process builders and workflows. I understand if it doesn't make much sense now, but the plan is to have the unamanaged package on Appexchange for specific customers only and allow direct customization in the subscriber Org.