# How do I publish apps on AppExchange for free as a freelancer?

Tags: appexchange, isv

I want to publish apps on AppExchange for free, can I do that as a freelancer without using any corporate email address and without paying any partners fee to Salesforce?

I have tried to register as a partner several times but all the times the partner org has been expiring and I don't remember receiving any login credentials to partners portal, so looks like I am unable to login to partners portal and publish any packages to appexchange. Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to sign up for a partner community using your dev org login credentials where you have built the package .

https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/partnerLogin

You will get access to publishing console once you are in partner community that should help you to  publish and manage your listing .

You will need an email other than Gmail because they say to add a corporate email.

All apps will go through the security review process however if your app is free you don't have to pay any fees. I maintain a free app and can confirm that I don't pay anything .I have used my mvp email address but you can get an email online .

There is a detailed post in this answer to help further

[How to host an Unmanaged package on salesforce appexchange](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116209/how-to-host-an-unmanaged-package-on-salesforce-appexchange)